# decreasing size of the text box in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Hi i want to put a textbox in my site for Search operation. But when i just use code to print textbox , the textbox covers whole of the page. My requirement is to get the textbox at the right side of my page and also the size of the text box must be very less.

This is what i tried,

```
  <div align="right">
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('Post') ?>
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('Search',array('type'=>'text','maxlength'=>'8')) ?>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me out ??

Comment: You can add style to resolve this issue.                              <?php  echo $this->Form->input('Search',array('type'=>'text','maxlength'=>'8', 'style'=>'width:200px; height:60px;')) ?>

Comment: cartina Thanks a lot, worked pretty well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `style` to your text box, for eg:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('Search',array('type'=>'text','maxlength'=>'8','style'=>'width:50px; height:20px;'));
```

Alternative is use `size` property of textbox.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Search',array('type'=>'text','maxlength'=>'8','size'=>'8'));
```

Comment: But best way is to cutomize the cake.generic.css file. Am I right? @Rikesh

Comment: @Usman - Yes, we can give class to the textbox & add style for that class in css file. But it will only helpful it is frequently required & not for just one text box.